# Text is not passed to my Share Extension while it is passed to other Share Extensions

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

What do I mean?

This is the list of extensions activated for some app downloaded from App Store:

There is **Message, Mail, Notes** and **Add to Wishlist** *(my extension)*.

[image]

This is what happens when I tap on message:

[image]

This is what happens when I tap on Mail:

[image]

And this is what happens when I tap on my extension:

[image]

**Why there is no text, while for other extensions THERE IS a text?**

This is how I register `NSExtensionActivationRule` for my extension:

[image]

How do I get the access to that text within my `SLComposeServiceViewController`?

Comment: What app are you sharing **from** in those screenshots?

Comment: Zillow Rentals - first free app from app store:) the link is: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-estate-by-zillow-search/id310738695?mt=8

Comment: I just tried out a fresh share extension with your settings and the text gets added automatically. I did not have to change anything in the `SLComposeServiceViewController`

Comment: I know, it works for others app for me also... but nor for this one... why? What it depends on?

Comment: Show some code maybe. Your activation rule is fine in a new project with no changes from the template that Xcode provides (I tried it). However it's possible your code is interfering somehow.